# Ess wav file loading and playing

Tags: java, audio, wav

I've been trying to simply load a wav file into an AudioChannel object and play it but it keeps giving me an error stating "Unable to load sound test.wav"

What I'm doing is:

```
AudioChannel currentsound;
Ess.start(this);
currentsound = new AudioChannel("test.wav");
currentsound.play();
```

The audio file is in the working directory too, any idea why it won't load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By working directory do you mean the data sub-directory in the sketch?  Processing reads from 'data/' in the Sketch folder.  Saving takes place in the Sketch folder itself.

Try this:

```
 currentsound = new AudioChannel("../test.wav");
```